# Is it possible to embedd this web app to my website

Tags: pages, embed, iframe

I am trying to embedd this website into my own website I have tried so using Iframe but the page is just blank.

The link I want to embedd is - https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1-Anchorage-Way-APT-1505-Freeport-NY-11520/2094629656_zpid/?fullpage=true

Or - https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1-Anchorage-Way-APT-1505-Freeport-NY-11520/2094629656_zpid?skinver=8&view=owner&fromapp=true&p=ios&appType=PA

My Iframe :

```
<iframe src="https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1-Anchorage-Way-APT-1505-Freeport-NY-11520/2094629656_zpid/" width="420" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"><iframe>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shortcodes and oembed ftw, iframes will get stripped out by WordPress for security reasons

Comment: Tom J Nowell Thanks for you help, I have the short code - [embed width="1000" height="500"]"URL"/[/embed] but all it does is display a hyperlink text.

Comment: The `embed` shortcode wasn't intended for iframes, it's the shortcode version of OEmbeds, you will need to add your own shortcode instead. Luckily how to embed iframes is a topic that has been heavily covered in numerous articles plugins and other questions on this site

Answer (score 0):

It may not work if the Zillow's server block being requested through iFrame. (You may check this at your console. Most big websites do block).

There is no  way to you do that using an iFrame. But in cases like this, I like to create a pop-up (triggered by a click, so browser will not block). Something like this:

```
<a id="open_in_popup" href="https://google.com">Open</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#open_in_popup').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();   
        var width  = 600,
            height = 400,
            left   = ($(window).width()  - width)  / 2,
            top    = ($(window).height() - height) / 2,
            url    = this.href,
            opts   = 'status=1' +
            ',width='  + width  +
            ',height=' + height +
            ',top='    + top    +
            ',left='   + left;

        window.open(url, '_blank', opts);

        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and my website does have SSL, is there an alternative way to maybe embedding it?

Comment: Bruno are you sure you haven't mixed those up? SSL is only an issue if you embed an insecure page inside a secure page, if the site in the iframe use HTTPS then that will not be an issue

Comment: Oh yeah. I guess I've inverted the rule.